# How do I convert an NSMutableString into a regular NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

How can I convert a NSMutable String into a regular NSString?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `[NSString stringWithString: yourMutableString]`

Comment: An autoreleased one, at that.

Comment: the converted nsstring not works like below //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]];

Answer (score 5):

```
[aMutableString copy]
```

will return a `NSString`.